# How to determine STATUS of executed query in 'Codeigniter'?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a situation, in which I have to check, whether the Query has executed Successfully or NOT.

In 'Codeigniter' we use `$this->db->affected_rows()` to determine affected rows by query executed.

However, I want something, that says, whether Query is executed and has not Failed to execute.

I have a certain situation, in which QUERY is RIGHT but affected rows will be mostly ZERO. How can I determine if affected rows are 0 as a result of an error or as a result of' NO change' in the database, even-though the right query has been executed.

I tried `if($this->db->error())`, but it sets as exists by 'Codeigniter' but in it's body there are 2 elements on SUCCESSFUL execution:

`["code" => "0", "msg" => ""]`

Should I consider that `$this->db->error('code')` will be `0` if Query is right and affected is 0 with no error?

Or any other statement is more appropriate to use?

Comment: @code-glider Thanks for review.

Comment: you should try with `$this->db->error()`. You can get reference from https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#handling-errors

Comment: That I already know but does it mean "code" => "0" means SUCCESSFUL Query Execution?

Comment: you can check with `$this->db->trans_status()`

Comment: @MayankVadiya
It always stays `bool(true)` on also wrong query when ENVIRONMENT is 'production'. So it is not proper my friend.

Comment: @HardikTrivedi Yes, when code=0 means there were No SQL Errors. If you do get a non zero code, that means you have an issue with your SQL or you are trying to insert a row that has a unique field usually stemming from a programming error or lack of checking which when its fixed should not occur in a "production" release.

Comment: What you want to check is the return value of your insert or update. Read the user guide on those.

Comment: What kind of query - select, insert, update, delete?  In answer to your question: The value of `code` as returned by `$this->db->error()` depends on your database. I'm pretty sure that for MySql code=0 means no error.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I got it dude. Thanks for the help. And all others also. Appriciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate the query like this:

```
$query = $this->db->get('table');

if ($query !== FALSE) {
    // success so access your result
}
else {
    // do something with $this->db->error()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this wil excute the query and determine if it run correctly or not

```
try{
    $this->db->query();
}catch(Exception $){
   $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).